# Shell script to copy data from remote server to Google Cloud Storage using Cron

Tags: gsutil

I want to Sync my server data to Google Cloud Storage to copy automatically using shell script. I don't know how to make script. Every time i need to use:
gsutil -m rsync -d -r [Source] gs://[Bucket-name]
If anyone knows the answer please help me!

Answer (score 0):

To automate the sync process use cron job:

1. Create a script to run with cron  $ nano backup.sh
2. Paste your gsutil command in the script  $ gsutil -m rsync -d -r [Source_PATH] gs://bucket-name
3. Make the script executable  $ chmod +x backup.sh
4. Based on your use case, put the shell script (backup.sh) in one of the below folders:   a) /etc/cron.daily b) /etc/cron.hourly c) /etc/cron.monthly d)
   /etc/cron.weekly
5. If you want to run this script for a specific time then go to the terminal and type: $ crontab -e
6. Then simply call out the script with cron as often as you want, for example, in midnight:  00 00 * * * /path/to/your/backup.sh

In case you are using Windows on your local server, The commands will be the same as above but make sure to use Windows path instead.